# Difference between Firebird isql and ODBC connection

Tags: odbc, firebird

I have problem with connecting to a Firebird database. It works perfectly, when I use `isql` tool, or program I have written using Borland dbExpress drivers. When I try to test ODBC connection it fails. I am using official Firebird ODBC drivers, version 2.0.

Strange facts:

- On other machines in the same network ODBC connection test fails, however:

  - When the same test is held in different network it seems to work
- When ODBC driver is installed on the same computer as Firebird server it also work flawlessly.
- Other ODBC drivers do work in this unfortunate network.

I ran out of ideas what might be the cause of this, and how to find root of all problems.

Comment: "It fails" doesn't say much. What's the error message?

Comment: Sadly -- it is error message: "Connection failed".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. ODBC driver was not smart enough to provide meaningful error message. It turned out, that it was unable to connect to database because of lack of installed proper version of Firebird client. `dbExpress` drivers were using `fbclient.dll` which was manually chosen, but somehow ODBC couldn't find it (it was in `system32` directory).

Answer (score 0):

isql or dbexpress is direct access to firebird (only use fbclient.dll)

ODBC is the old access for windows technology

You'd better use OLE DB if you can.
Here is a [comparison](http://www.ibprovider.com/eng/documentation/firebird_interbase_odbc_drivers.html) between ODBC and ADO